Cookies vs Local Storage
I am developing an online tool that features various modules, including settings for language, color schemes, timers, scoring, and more. However, I am facing challenges regarding the persistence of these configurations.
I have already implemented cookies to save these settings, but I'm concerned about sensitive data. For example, regarding the scoring system, I've encrypted the score values to prevent users from simply modifying their cookie to "99999" to max out their scores on the site.
Hosting these sensitive elements on the server might not be an option since I do not want to include a database for such basic features in the MVP, but I also wish to avoid any possibilities for arbitrary changes.
When users accumulate points, they unlock additional colors. How can I securely save this information—that they have unlocked the colors—without allowing them to simply copy and transfer the cookies to others?
In essence, my question is: How can I securely host sensitive information (such as site points and unlocked items) without overly complicating the MVP?
Already implemented: UUID, js-cookie, crypto-js, cookie-parser

You absolutely need back end validation, theres no getting around that. Authorization can not be implemented purely on the client side. The cookie/jwt would need to be signed by a secret key private to the server. All modifications to it would be via API calls (only server can produce valid signed cookie/jwt). Crucially though, if you want to prevent sharing the cookies, the user identifier must be part of the signed cookie/jwt. And that means you 100% need a users database as you need to relate the cookie/jwt to an individual user. Sharing  then would be same as user sharing their user/pass.
